# Sprite Sheet Texture not being rendered

Tags: opengl, c++, textures, sprites, sdl

I'm making space invaders (in OpenGL/SDL) and I've run into a problem
when trying to draw the sprite for the spaceship from the spritesheet.
In my entity class, I have a pointer for the sprite that belongs to the current instance of the object. In main, I make an instance on the heap of the
sheetSprite, passing in the u,v,width, and height of the sprite for
the parameters and then storing this reference in the mySprite field
of the spaceship entity.

The coordinates provided by the texture atlas are:                      `<SubTexture name="playerShip2_green.png" x="112" y="866" width="112" height="75"/>`

To draw the spaceship, I call the draw method from its "mySprite"
attribute. For some reason, only a white square is being rendered
without the actual texture. What could be causing the problem? The relevant code is below:

```
class SheetSprite {
public:

    SheetSprite(unsigned int textureID, float u, float v, float width, float height, float size, ShaderProgram program)
        :textureID(textureID), u(u), v(v), width(width), height(height), size(size), program(program) {}

    void Draw() {
        //glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
        glUseProgram(program.programID);
        GLfloat texCoords[] = {
            u, v + height,
            u + width, v,
            u, v,
            u + width, v,
            u, v + height,
            u + width, v + height
        };
        float aspect = width / height;
        float vertices[] = {
            -0.5f * size * aspect, -0.5f * size,
            0.5f * size * aspect, 0.5f * size,
            -0.5f * size * aspect, 0.5f * size,
            0.5f * size * aspect, 0.5f * size,
            -0.5f * size * aspect, -0.5f * size ,
            0.5f * size * aspect, -0.5f * size };
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
        //float vertices2[] = { -0.5, -0.5, 0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 0.5, -0.5, 0.5 };
        glVertexAttribPointer(program.positionAttribute, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, vertices);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(program.positionAttribute);
        //float texCoords2[] = { 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
        glVertexAttribPointer(program.texCoordAttribute, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, texCoords);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(program.texCoordAttribute);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(program.positionAttribute);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(program.texCoordAttribute);
    }
    float size;
    unsigned int textureID;
    float u;
    float v;
    float width;
    float height;
    ShaderProgram program;
};


class Entity {

public:
    Matrix modelMatrix, projectionMatrix, viewMatrix;
    float width, height = 1.0;
    float xDir, yDir = 0.0;
    float posX, posY = 0.0;
    float objSpeed = 0.0;
    float rotState = 0.0;
    float u, v, spr_width, spr_hght, spr_size = 0.0;
    unsigned int textureID;
    ShaderProgram program;
    //GLuint spriteSheetTexture = LoadTexture("sheet.png");
    SheetSprite* mySprite;

    Entity(float wid, float hght, float xDirect, float yDirect,
        float xPosition, float yPosition, float speed, float rState, ShaderProgram program) : width(wid), height(hght),
        xDir(xDirect), yDir(yDirect), posX(xPosition), posY(yPosition), objSpeed(speed), rotState(rState), program(program) {}

//Extra methods
};

//instantiation of sheetSprite in main

Entity spaceship(0.1f, 0.7f, 1.0f, 1.0f, -5.1f, 0.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f, program);
    spaceship.objSpeed = 10;

    GLuint spriteSheetTexture = LoadTexture("sheet.png");
    spaceship.mySprite = new SheetSprite(spriteSheetTexture, 112.0f / 1024.0f, 866.0f / 1024.0f, 112.0f / 1024.0f, 75.0f / 1024.0f, 0.7, program);


//in the game loop

spaceship.mySprite->Draw();
```

Comment: Does `glGetError()` return any errors? If so, find out what line exactly triggers it.

Comment: Where would I call ```glGetError()``` ?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat  I'm using Visual Studio btw.

Comment: Just put it anywhere in the main loop.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yeah, just put it in the main game loop and I'm not seeing any output from it

Comment: If it always returns 0, then I think the problem is that you're using client-side arrays - you pass actual pointer as the last argument for `glVertexAttribPointer`. This is not supported in new OpenGL. Try to use VBOs or try to initilalize lower GL version.

Comment: Hi yeah, I think the problem might have to do with the u/v coordinates not retaining their value. Here is a gist of the code: https://gist.github.com/loremIpsum1771/4c0898cea937c3ccbfd3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the shader program needed to be passed to the SheetSprite class as a pointer instead of just being passed as an object.

Comment: If your problem was that your class was incorrectly copied, you may want to ensure that it is properly copyable or noncopyable instead of accidentally doing the wrong thing when copied or assigned.